# How to proof that $e^{x^2}$ does not have a primitive function?

Tags: calculus

I was wondering how you proof that the function $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ does not have a primitive function. I have heard en read this example multiple times, but I don't know how to proof it.

Comment: Of course it has. Take $\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: I mean a "elementary" primitive function, so written using exponents, logs, trigonometric functions, roots, ... . So not with an integral.